# Can't create new AMQPSSLConnection "Broken pipe or closed connection"

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect to a Rabbit server with

```
   require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
   use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPSSLConnection;
   $connection = new AMQPSSLConnection ('example.com', 5671, 'uname', '***', '/some/vhost');
```

And all I get is an exception 'Broken pipe or closed connection'. The server people ave confirmed that my connection parameters are correct. I cannot figure out what to do.

I am using PHP 7 and php-amqplib v2.7.2.

Help ?

```
#0 vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader.php(149): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read(7)
#1 vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader.php(106): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread(7)
#2 vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection.php(522): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read(7)
#3 vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection.php(570): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame(3)
#4 vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel.php(225): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel(0, 3)
#5 vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel.php(335): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->next_frame(3)
#6 vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection.php(214): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->wait(Array, false, 3)
#7 vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection.php(189): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->connect()
#8 vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection.php(60): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->__construct('t
```

Comment: What is logged by the AMQP broker?

Comment: @LukeBakken thanks. No idea what is in the logs but I found that I missed the ssl options parameter:
  $connection = new AMQPSSLConnection ('example.com', 5671, 'uname', '***', '/some/vhost',  ['ssl_version' => 'TLSv1']);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I spent much time before I fixed it, because I didn't have admin access to RabbitMQ and logs. I've solved this problem by just changing the `AMQPLAIN` login method to `PLAIN`. I used `AMQPStreamConnection` instead of `AMQPSSLConnection`, but the syntax is very similar.

AMQPStreamConnection:

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
   config('amqp.host'),
   config('amqp.port'),
   config('amqp.username'),
   config('amqp.password'),
   config('amqp.vhost'),
   false,
  'PLAIN'
);
```

AMQPSSLConnection:

```
$connection = new AMQPSSLConnection(
   config('amqp.host'),
   config('amqp.port'),
   config('amqp.username'),
   config('amqp.password'),
   config('amqp.vhost'),
   [], // Your SSL options
   ['login_method' => 'PLAIN'] // Your options
);
```